# How to handle shared css file in react

Tags: reactjs, sass

What is the best way to handle shared `scss` file in react?
Assuming I have the following file

```
// variables.scss
$primary: rgb(1,2,3);
$secondary: rgb(2,3,4);
```

And I have multiple components who need to use those colors.
of-course every component has its own `scss` file and I import this file in component `jsx` file, do I need to `import` this file multiple times in every component who need to use those variables?

If I do `import` this file in every component `scss` file does `webpack` with `sass-loader` know to handle it and import it once?

UPDATE: 
To explain the question better this is my issue:
I have a component A
this is the jsx file

```
// A.jsx
import React from 'react';
import './A.scss'

//more code here...
```

A `scss` looks like this:

```
//A.scss
import '../../variables.scss';
```

and I also have component B
this is the `jsx` file

```
// B.jsx
import React from 'react';
import './B.scss'
```

B `scss` looks like this:

```
//B.scss
import '../../variables.scss';
```

Now as you can see both `A.scss` and `B.scss` imports the variables, is this the right way? If yes does `webpack sass-loader` know not import the same file twice? If not what is the right way?

Comment: You want to use `$primary`(eg) in jsx/scss files?

Comment: @Raviteja in the scss files yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598996/sass-use-variables-across-multiple-files

Comment: @Raviteja Thanks. I know this solution but in react I import the component `scss` file inside the component `scss` so there is no need for a base file which imports all the files, because jsx already does that

Comment: What do you need then?

Comment: @Raviteja I update the question :) thanks for your help