# sass variables aren't working in Ionic-4 while importing all the files at one place

Tags: angular, sass, angular7, ionic4

I have created a folder name `variables` inside the `app`. Inside the folder I have created my sass file named `customColor.scss`. So now in `customColor.scss` I have my colors posted below.

**customColor.scss**

```
$color-primary: #1706b3;
$color-primary-light: #393b8f;
$color-primary-dark: #28b485;
$color-secondary-light: #ffb900;
$color-secondary-dark: #ff7730;
$color-tertiary-light: #2998ff;
$color-tertiary-dark: #5643fa;
$color-grey-light-1: #f7f7f7;
$color-grey-light-2: #eee;
$color-grey-dark: #777;
$color-grey-dark-2: #999;
$color-grey-dark-3: #333;
$color-white: #fff;
$color-black: #000;
```

Now in my `app.comoponent.scss` I have imported all my internal folder `scss` files as below

```
@import "./variables/customColor.scss";
@import "./tab2/tab2.page.scss";
@import "./tab3/tab3.page.scss";
```

My custom color are working fine in `tab2.page.scss` but not working in `tab3.page.scss`. I'm getting the below error.

```
./src/app/tab3/tab3.page.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

    background-color: $color-black;
                     ^
      Undefined variable: "$color-black".
      in D:\myApp\src\app\tab3\tab3.page.scss (line 44, column 23)
```

**Note:** It's working if I import my customColor.scss to tab3.page.scss.
I'm completely new to Ionic, Angular and SASS.
Not able to understand that where does this goes wrong. Any leads or fixes? TIA

Comment: did you import __customColor.scss__ to tab2?

Comment: I didn't. I'm importing all the files in `app.component.css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each file is **independent unit**, which means each one have his **own scope**.

I don't know why tab2 is not throwing a compile error,
but tab2 and tab3 is **encapsulated** from customColors which means you need to import customColors inside them.

**customColor.scss**

```
$color-primary: #1706b3;
$color-primary-light: #393b8f;
$color-primary-dark: #28b485;
$color-secondary-light: #ffb900;
$color-secondary-dark: #ff7730;
$color-tertiary-light: #2998ff;
$color-tertiary-dark: #5643fa;
$color-grey-light-1: #f7f7f7;
$color-grey-light-2: #eee;
$color-grey-dark: #777;
$color-grey-dark-2: #999;
$color-grey-dark-3: #333;
$color-white: #fff;
$color-black: #000;
```

**tab2.page.scss**

```
@import "../variables/customColor.scss";
```

**tab3.page.scss**

```
@import "../variables/customColor.scss";
```

maybe add **globals.scss**

```
@import "./variables/customColor.scss";
@import "./tab2/tab2.page.scss";
@import "./tab3/tab3.page.scss";
```

and then in **app.comoponent.scss**

```
@import "./customColor.scss";
```

Comment: Actually when I used sass,I used to import all the `scss` files to one `main.scss` and will convert that to css using `"watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"` inside script in `package.json`. In ionic and angular that doesn't work in that way?

Comment: This is what i mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/17599322/9380480

Comment: @SaiManoj component in angular are encapsulated which means you can't.

Comment: Thanks.Got this cleared. So now if I remove ```styleurl``` in my ts then it works

Comment: @SaiManoj you could remove the styleUrl, import everything into main styles.scss and use global styles for the application but then you will lose angular functionality like **:host{}**, try combain both of the methods.

Comment: Thanks mate, you have cleared all my queries. Accepted and up-voted your answer.