# SASS / Gulp: Using mixins and vars from another file

Tags: sass, gulp, mixins, gulp-watch

I have the following folder structure setup:

```
theme
   - assets
      - sass
         - _theme-styles.scss
      - _styles.scss
   - modules
      - hero
         - hero.html
         - hero.scss
         - hero.css (gulp will compile this file)
```

**_theme-styles.scss** is really simple at the moment and looks like this:

```
// VARS
$white: #FFFFFF;
```

**_styles.scss** looks like this:

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins.scss";

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0px,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 786px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
);

// Import Globals
@import "config/**.scss";
```

And for reference, my `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var paths = {
    styles: {
        src: 'modules/**/*.scss',
        dest: 'modules'
    }
}
function scss() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
}
exports.scss = scss
function watch() {

    scss()

    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, scss);
}
exports.watch = watch
```

**What I'm trying to do**

I want to reference a `variables` and `mixins` defined in other files. For example, with my current workflow set as is, in **hero.scss** I have:

`.hero { background: $white; }`

I've defined this variable in **_theme-styles.scss** and want to be able to use it here without redefining.

Similarly, when using mixins, i.e. example below:

```
.hero{
    @include media-breakpointup(md){
        padding: 60px;
    }
}
```

The above `mixin` is defined in the `bootstrap` node module folder. But when referencing these I get `undefined errors` when running `gulp watch`.

Answer (score 0):

**At the top** of `hero.scss` you should

```
@use 'pathsToYourOtherSCSSFiles';
```

like:

```
@use '../assets/sass/theme-styles';
@use '../assets/styles';
and same to the bootstrap file with the mixin defined
```

I didn't test those paths but they should be the relative path from your `hero.scss` file to the ones you want to `@use`.  See https://sass-lang.com/guide `Modules`

Comment: Is there any way to do this without adding the above to every module I create?

Comment: The only possible alternative is to have one scss file at the top of your modules or assets folder that `@use` all the files there and then each child scss below that `@use`'s that one file.  I haven't tried it but I believe you can chain `@use` calls in that way.  In any case you're going to have to `@use`  something into each of your modules - either one file that collects all the `@use`s or each of them separately.

Comment: I was looking into a more "master file" generated approach. For example like the one answered in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598996/sass-use-variables-across-multiple-files . However, as you can see in my original question, using @import still comes with undefined errors

Comment: These lines look incorrrect: `@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";` did you mean `@import "./././node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";` or possibly `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";`?