# @import not pulling vars from master files to other files

Tags: css, sass

I have a workflow setup where I have all the config `scss` files housed under one folder. I then have a `_styles.scss` file where I'm `importing` all of these files.

Now, in another file, `hero.scss`, I'm referencing variables which are in those config files. But I get undefined errors.

I had a look further and found this [other question from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598996/sass-use-variables-across-multiple-files), seems like the best answer is suggesting the same approach I have adopted, but it's not working for me?

**Folder structure:**

```
theme
   - assets
      - sass
         - config
            - _variables.scss
      - _styles.scss
   - modules
      - hero
         - hero.html
         - hero.scss
```

`_variables.scss`

```
$white: #FFF;
$black: #000;
```

`_styles.scss'

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins.scss";
@import "config/variables.scss";
```

`hero.scss`

```
.hero{
   color: $white;
}
```

None of the imports work, because when trying to use the Bootstrap mixins i.e.

```
.hero{
    @include media-breakpoint-up(sm){
        color: $white;
    }
}
```

They don't work either, even though I've @imported them too.
**Edit**:

If I do the following in `hero.scss`

```
@import "../../assets/sass/styles.scss";

.hero{
   background: $white;
}
```

Whilst the vars will now be recognised, when running gulp, all the styles from the files imported in `styles/scss`, they'll now be compiled alongside my module code.

**For example:**

My `gulpfile.js` for reference:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');

var paths = {
    styles: {
        src: 'modules/**/*.scss',
        dest: 'modules'
    }
}

function scss() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
}
exports.scss = scss
function watch() {

    scss();

    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, scss);
}
exports.watch = watch
```

What the above is essentially doing is compiling `scss` files found in subfolders of the parent folder `modules`.

With this `@import "../../assets/sass/styles.scss";` now added  to `hero.scss` (which is housed under modules), it's now adding my config code to that modules css file.

**Complete folder structure:**

```
theme
    - assets
       - sass
          - config
             - _variables.scss
       - _client-styles.scss
       - styles.scss   
    - modules
      - hero
         - hero.html
         - hero.scss
         - hero.css (running gulp will compile this)
```

So `hero.css`, with the import is now contains code from `hero.scss` and `client-styles.scss` for example. Whereas I only need it to compile the sass from `hero.scss`.

Comment: By the looks of it you need to import styles into `hero.scss` -> `@import "../../assets/sass/styles";`

Comment: @MrT is right I think. Also you have to import hero.scss somewhere (_styles.scss?)...

Comment: @Leon Vuković `_styles.scss` is partial and won't be compiled to css if the setup is correct.

Comment: @MrT - Hi, I've updated my question to state why I can't use that approach

Comment: If you need just variables and mixins inside your `hero.scss`, then import just what you need. So `@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins.scss";
@import "../../assets/config/variables.scss"; ` _you may need to correct paths_