# Unable to import sass variables from one scss file to another

Tags: reactjs, sass

In my React app, I have a file called `_variables.scss` with the following code. It contains variables that I want to use in all my .scss files:

```
$navy: #264653;
$green: #2A9D8F;
$yellow: #E9C46A;
$orange: #F4A261;
$red: #E76F51;

$title-font: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", sans-serif;
$text-font: "Raleway", sans-serif;
```

I want to use the variables in another .scss file. This is my code in the other file:

```
@use './design/variables' as v;

* {
  font-family: v.$text-font;
}
```

However, instead of recognizing the variable, my React app returns the following error:
[image]

I have already checked that the path of the file is the correct one.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Not sure about `@use`. Try `@import './design/variables'`. Also just `$text-font` but not `v.$text-font`.

Comment: Yes, it worked!

Comment: However, I have read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598996/sass-use-variables-across-multiple-files/61500282#61500282 that `@import` is deprecated and that we should use `@use`. How would you solve the error using `@use` ? And why is `@import` going to be deprecated?

Comment: Not sure. If you are using `@use` try using `#{v.$text-font}`

Comment: It does not work this way 
````
SassError: Invalid CSS after "  font-family: #{v": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$text-font};"
        on line 4 of /Users/arnau/Desktop/PROJECTES/diverteach/src/App.scss
>>   font-family: #{v.$text-font};

   ------------------^
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Node-Sass as most are. `@use` is only supported by Dart-Sass yet and probably forever. The announcement that `@import` would be depricated was made 5 years ago.

Comment: Should I use dart-sass instead of node-sass, then? Or should I not bother and keep using node-sass?

Comment: @ArnoldGee, There's absolutely nothing wrong about using Node-Sass, Dart-Sass is the primary implementation and gets every new feature first, meaning its also not the most stable. And as said the announcement to depricate `@import` was made 5 years ago.