# SCSS Variable not applying globally

Tags: css, sass, live-sass-compiler

I have a variable and gallery partial: `_variables.scss`, `_gallery.scss`

When I import the variables file, which contains only one line `$primary: #e0291a;`, it works in the main `style.scss` file, but not in the `_gallery.scss` file.

My project is only going to grow, but do I really need to import the variables file in every single subsequent partial file?

I'm using VSCode Live Sass Compiler. The variables work with a custom webpack/laravel mix script I've set up a few years back, but not with this extension.

Is there a way to streamline the variable import without adding the line in every single scss file?

`style.scss` (main file):

```css
@use 'variables';
@use 'gallery';
```

`_variables.scss`:

```css
$primary: #ffffff;
```

`_gallery.scss`:

```
#gallery {
    background-color: $primary // <--- Throws error of undefined variable
}
```

Comment: have you considered using CSS variables instead?

Comment: You just need to add `@use "path-to/variables" as *;` (if you want to access variables without a namespace like your doing above) to the top of `_gallery.scss` because it doesn't have access to the loaded members in `_variables`. So in short, yes you need to give that `_gallery.scss` partial knowledge of loaded members from `_variables.scss`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SASS - use variables across multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598996/sass-use-variables-across-multiple-files)

Comment: @ArtiomB [`@import`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) at-rules are gradually being phased out in dart-sass so its probably best to move forward with a `@use` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when using Nuxt 2 you are using the Nuxt Style Resources V1 - lots of instructions out there don't say that